# Need access to model on jquery HTTP (Ajax) request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to have access to the model with data from the form when i do an http ajax request.I am not sure if this is possible, so I might have to include the data I need in my request?

From the view I have a jquery.ajax call

```
$.ajax({
   url: this.href,
   cache: false,
   success: function (html) { $("#editorPriceRows").append(html); }
});
```

And in my controller I have the action

```
public ActionResult NewDateRow(MyModel model)
{
   // here I want to check some of the values i filled out in my form but have not posted yet and depending on this value, I will set some data in the model I am passing to the partial view.       
    return PartialView("_DateEditRow", partialModel);
}
```

I need to check a date in my form to see what data I need to set inn the model that is passed to the partialview. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, my problem with the code above would be that the model is always null.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your model directly from jQuery but you can try the following line:

```
 var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

Then you have to pass the data to your controller action (cache: false, data:...,).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using `@Ajax.actionlink`
ex:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Any friedly name", "YourAction", new { uaid = Model.xyzclass.Parametername}, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "whateverurplacholder forholdingmsg",OnSuccess = "xyz", OnFailure = "xyz" } })
```

this will work,but since this ajax call, you may not be able to see view source of this once it is executed

`$ajaxrequest(....)` you can check the syntax.

you could still do that jquery

thanks